# Calculate the grid column value with total value in extjs4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, sencha-architect, extjs4.2

I have the grid with two columns: Target and Target Percentage. I am getting Target value from store. I need to calculate Total and Target percentage value using Jan/Total Jan*100. I want a summary for target %. Can anybody tell me how to do this?

I need to calculate the total manually

E.g

```
Month  Target      Target %
   Jan     50       **50/100*100**
   Mon     50       50/100*100
   Total   100
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Probably you want this in your model.

```
{
    name : 'Target %',
    convert : function( value, record ) {
                   var target = (record.get('Target')/total)*100;
                   return target;
    }   
    type: 'number'
},
```

Comment: ohh sorry my bad,I didnt see the total field.Would it be a problem if the total is calculated server side and then loaded to the grid.

Comment: @Amit Aviv can u help me in this problem